# Length of SHA1 hash to identify an object?

Tags: hash

Can I create a really short SHA1 hash to uniquely identify an object that would typically have an id like `1300992607`?

This is relatively a theoretical question but how short can a SHA1 hash be and still be unique for an objects id? Please help me if not asking the right question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, a hash doesn't work that way.

You can create a hash for the id, and just take as many bits you like from it. The more bits you use, the less likely it is that you get a hash that is the same for two different id, but no matter how many bits you use from the hash there is still no guarantee that there will never be a collision.

Comment: @Joseph Silvashy: Yes. A hash is only guaranteed to be unique the other way around, i.e. if you have two different hash codes, they can't come from the same original value, no matter how small the hash codes are and how big the original values are.